Long equation break
We are formatting our article using the journal format available here: http://cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/template.html
The following is contained in our article. Unfortunately, given the length of the involved equations, they keep going to the right area (passing the margin of the text):

How to control-modify this so that it remains within the margin of the text without extending to the right? \sloppy didn't work for this one.
\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart}
\textwidth=4.5in
\usepackage{dsfont}
\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around text block

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item %\sloppy

\item For all $q \in \N,\left\{U \in \mathcal{B}\left(E\right),
\lim_{r \to +\infty}\int_{E_q}\left|\mathds{1}_U\left(g_r\left(x\right)\right)-
\mathds{1}_{U}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right|^p\,
\mathrm{d} \mu(x) =0\right\}$
 is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and $\left\{U \in \mathcal{B}\left(E\right),
\mu\left(g_0^{-1}\left(U\right) \cap E_q\right)=\mu\left(g^{-1}\left(U\right)\cap 
E_q\right)\right\}$
 is a $\lambda$-system on $E.$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


Could you make this a complete example with the necessary commands?  And format this so that the code looks the way you want?  At first glance, it seems like $q\in\N should be a separate expression from the rest, and the rest through "is a $\sigma$-algebra..." could be in a \[...\].

You should remove almost all the \left\right \left(x\right) should be (x) which has better spacing, and for the longer terms left..right prevents line breaking

I tried all these suggestions, but the problem remains

I've taken the liberty of making your code snippet minimally compilable and posting a screenshot. Feel free to revert.

By all means, do get rid of all \left and \right auto-sizing directives. Yes, all of them. Not only are they not required, they actually interfere with the line-breaking options that would otherwise be available to TeX's paragraph builder algorithm.
Do also note that
For all $q \in \N,\{U \in \mathcal{B} ...

isn't right because q \in \N and \{U \in \mathcal{B} ... are separate "math atoms". Hence, do please write
For all $q \in \N$, $\{U \in \mathcal{B} ...

Semantically speaking, this change makes the comma a part of the sentence syntax rather than part of the math material.
Once you've performed these steps, it takes only one judiciously-placed \allowbreak directive to get rid of the overfull-line problem.


That said, I think your readers would much appreciate if you chose to typeset the two long formulas as displayed equations:

Note: Still no \left and \right directives anywhere in sight...

\documentclass[10pt,reqno]{amsart} % is this correct?
\textwidth=4.5in 

\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,dsfont}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\N{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand\indU{\mathds{1}^{}_U} % indicator function

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item For all $q\in\N$, $\{ U\in\mathcal{B}(E),
\lim_{r\to\infty} \int_{E_q} 
\abs{ \indU(g_r(x))-\indU(g(x)) }^p 
\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) \allowbreak  = 0 \}$ 
is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and 
$\{ U\in\mathcal{B}(E),\mu(g_0^{-1}(U) \cap E_q)
=\mu(g^{-1}(U)\cap E_q) \}$ is a $\lambda$-system on~$E$.

\bigskip\addtocounter{enumi}{-1} % just for this example

%% now the version that displays the two long formulas
\item For all $q\in\N$,
\[
\{ U\in\mathcal{B}(E),
\lim_{r\to\infty} {\textstyle \int_{E_q}}
\abs{ \indU(g_r(x))-\indU(g(x)) }^p 
\,\mathrm{d}\mu(x) = 0 \} % '\allowbreak' not needed
\]
is a $\sigma$-algebra on $E$ and 
\[
\{ U\in\mathcal{B}(E), \mu(g_0^{-1}(U) \cap E_q)
=\mu(g^{-1}(U)\cap E_q) \}
\]
is a $\lambda$-system on~$E$.

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Is it possible instead to use \sloppy?

@mathex - Have you given it a try? (Hint: The \left and \right directives will still interfere with whatever \sloppy can do.)

Yup, it didn't work, but curious why? (To be noted that somewhere else in the article we used \sloppy, where we also used \left...\right, yet it worked well)

@mathex - As I wrote earlier, \left ... \right interferes with TeX's line-breaking algorithm. Not even \sloppy can help you there. By the way, why do you employ \left and \right so profligately? Please see the posting Is it ever bad to use \left and \right? for a longer discussion of why sprinkling \left and \right all over the place is not a good idea. In fact, it's a bad idea...
